# Code for plot for my case

Tags: plot, netlogo

in some patches i have "lonely" seller without buyer or lonely buyer without seller. in this case I code it so that their trade_Price is 0. in plot I want to show trade_Price. I code it so :

```
plot mean [trade_Price] of turtles
```

will it calculate the trade_Price which are 0 or? I want that it calculates only trade_Prices which are > 0. how can I code it in plot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want that it calculates only trade_Prices which are > 0":

```
plot mean [trade_Price] of turtles with [trade_Price > 0]
```

"will it calculate the trade_Price which are 0 or?":

What happens when you try it?  NetLogo is a very flexible tool for experimentation.

(Runle, some--not all--of your questions in StackOverflow make it seem as if you didn't take the time to read NetLogo Manual and NetLogo Dictionary, or to experiment on your own before asking questions.  It's important for you to do your part of the work before asking questions here, rather than asking us to do the work for you.  Then, give us more information about what you tried and what didn't work when you ask a question.  You will learn a *lot* more following this strategy than by asking questions before you have investigated on your own.  I know that sometimes it's frustrating to work on a problem when you're first learning a programming language, but you will learn things you didn't expect to learn, and you'll get better at problem-solving on your own.)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but i tried to do it and i checked also another model examples too. it takes much more time for me to try all of the codes, I am just beginner in netlogo and i have to give my model to my supervisor in 2 days thats why i cannot try every code. I write codes here which I thought are the right codes but may be with another modification. And before asking a question  I checked many codes too. anyway thank you for your tips and help:)

Comment: What Mars said, times 10.